# Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Messaging version 10.0.2 and flutterLocalNotification version 6.0.0. Whenever I run my notification using firebase messaging for when my app is in background I keep getting in the console this exception *Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used* even when I have created a Notification channel using the flutter localNotification plugin.
Although, this works perfectly when the app is in foreground
Here's my Manifest.xml file

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.app">
  <application
    android:label="app"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
          android:value="app"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Here's also my code to create the notification channel

```
 static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"));

  static void createChannelAndDisplay(RemoteMessage message) async {
    final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
    final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "app", "app_channel", "my app channel",
          importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high));

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      message.notification!.title,
      message.notification!.body,
      notificationDetails,
     );
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Could you try to replace ```android:value="app"``` by something from ```string.xml``` file ? I mean using ```android:value="@string/channel_id_here"``` ?

Comment: I don’t know about the string.xml file and I don’t see it on my project structure or am I to create one

Comment: You find it under ```android``` folder, search for ```res/values/string.xml```

Comment: what I see is styles.xml

Comment: Create then this file as ```strings.xml``` (with 's'), add this content to the file ```<resources>
    <string name="channel_id">channel_id_here</string>
</resources>```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Show me the final code if possible ?

Comment: `<resources>
    <string name="channel_id">myapp</string> 
</resources>                                                                                                     <meta-data
              android:name=.  "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
              android:value=""@string/myapp"/>`

Comment: the name of the string is ```channel_id``` and not ```myapp```, you should use ```@string/channel_id``` instead, *you have double "" too*

Comment: *my app* is my apps channel Id

Comment: I know, but the id if myapp is channel_id

Comment: please I don't understand your last comment, can you write the code explicitly if my app's id is **my app**

Comment: Replace ```android:value="@string/myapp"``` by android:value=""@string/channel_id" , and inside ```AndroidNotificationDetails()``` replace ```app``` by ```R.string.channel_id```

Comment: don’t worry I’ve found a better way to solve the issue, your solution wasn’t working. Thanks tho

Comment: You can share your fix here as answer, for others

Comment: I just followed through with the firebase messaging and flutter local notification docs